# Set title of page using custom page template

Tags: wp-head, wp-title

Most of the related questions are still unanswered or have very little information.
I have a custom theme for my [website](http://www.animalswecare.com) and use WordPress SEO for titles.

All the article pages work fine, except for the pages which are created by template, i.e. [/adopt-a-dog](http://www.animalswecare.com/adopt-a-dog/)
and [/dog-breeds](http://www.animalswecare.com/dog-breeds/). These pages have a list of adoption entries and dog breeds. Adopt-a-dog uses `adoption-search.php` as a template and `adopt-details.php` to display individual results. Where as dog-breeds uses `breeds.php` to display the dog breeds page, as well as individual breeds.

I tried adding the title in `header.php` using condition `is_page_template('adopt-details.php')` but that doesn't work. I also tried to modify `functions.php` but that didn't work either.

It shows the title as set in WordPress SEO, i.e. "Adopt a dog, save a life". Instead, if the adoption result is for puppy Fodo, I want to set the title to something like: `"Adoption details for " . pet_name . ", " . pet_city`

Is there a way to set the title from a page template, or set the title based on URL?

Code that I have tried:

```
if ( ( get_permalink() == 'http://animalswecare.com/dog-breeds/' || 
    get_permalink() == 'http://animalswecare.com/cat-breeds/' ) && 
    uri_segment( 2 ) != '0' ) 
{ 
    ?><title><?php echo uri_segment( 2 ); ?></title><?php 
} else {
    ?><title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title><?php
}
```

Second option that I tried is disabling WP SEO when the page is `adopt-detail-dog`. On adding this code, the URL shows as title. That is okay if somehow the URL could be cleaned to show as text.

```
if ( is_page( 589 ) ) { 
    global $wpseo_front;
    remove_action( 'wp_head', array( $wpseo_front, 'head' ), 1 );
    ?><title>hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</title><?php
} else {
    ?><title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title><?php
}
```

This changes the title to show page URL, but doesn't show "hiiiiiiiiiiii" as title.

Comment: Add codes you have tried so far for a better understanding

Comment: @Gyanendra added code

Comment: see my answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/269862/how-to-set-custom-title-of-custom-page-template/338510#338510

Answer (score 2):

For dog breeds, I added the following code to template pages, overwriting the WP SEO functions:

```
function assignPageTitle() { // To set page title
    global $resultarray;
    return $resultarray->breed_title;
} 

if ( uri_segment( 2 ) != '0' ) {
    add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'assignPageTitle' ); // WP SEO function overwritten
}
```

For a list of other WP SEO functions, see [this](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/api/).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following [code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62415/changing-document-title-only-on-a-custom-page-template/62417#62417) to your functions.php file:

```
function wpse62415_filter_wp_title( $title ) {
    // Return a custom document title for
    // the my-custom-page custom page template
    if ( is_page_template( 'my-custom-page.php' ) ) {
        return 'I\'m the my-custom-page details page';
    }
    // Otherwise, don't modify the document title
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpse62415_filter_wp_title' );
```