# How to set custom title of custom page template?

Tags: title, wp-title

How to set custom title of custom page template?

I try use `wp_title` filter but it's not working.

Comment: Are you using the filter before calling the `wp_head`?

Answer (score 2):

[Reference](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62415/changing-document-title-only-on-a-custom-page-template/62417?newreg=9e9601805cd5461e9ab988dc3e605854)

Got success by adding this code to `your-page-template.php` file before `get_header()` function:

```
function my_page_title() {
    return 'Your value is '; // add dynamic content to this title (if needed)
}
add_action( 'pre_get_document_title', 'my_page_title' );
```

Comment: This should be added in the themes `function.php` file.

Comment: hope this worked from the template file but doesn't

Comment: Your theme must `add_theme_support('title-tag')` in `functions.php`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a conditional and check if you are on a custom post type page, and then update the title:

```
function my_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    if (is_single('post-tyle')){
        // Update the title here, for example : $title .= $title . $post->post_title;
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'my_wp_title', 10, 2 );
```

However, your theme must support `wp_title`. For doing so, add this in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

Answer (score -1):

There are times when you cannot do this from functions.php (you don't have the data you want to output yet). For these cases:

make a new copied header file `header-mycustom.php` and load it in your template

```
global $newtitle;
$newtitle="New Title";
get_header("mycustom");
```

in the `header-mycustom.php` replace `wp_head` with the following:

```
<?php 
ob_start();
wp_head();
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
global $newtitle;
$output=preg_replace("/<title>(.+)<\/title>/","<title>$newtitle</title>",$output);
echo $output;   
?>
```

(This is the first time I feel I have to hack WP for such common task.)

Comment: [That's because you don't.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/320290/175203)