# I want change custom title in custom wordpress php page

Tags: php, functions, wp-title

H Guys, I have a page details.php in WordPress which is run like this [domain.com/product-details?id=706494861]

And I want to show the product title as  in the head. I have a listable WordPress theme. I have tried these solutions as well. but the title is not changing still showing my default page title which is Product Details

My details.php The product data I receiving

```
    <?php /* Template Name: product-details */

get_header();
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>


  <?php
  $found = "0";
  $url = 'https://domain.com/xml';
  $rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
  $custom_title = $item->title;
  foreach ($rss->channel as $channel) {
    foreach ($channel->item as $item) {
      if ($_GET['id'] == $item->id) {
        $found = "1";
        echo '<div class="image-container"><img src="' . $item->image_link . '" > </div>';
        echo '<div class="contentspace"></div>';
        echo '<div class="content"><h1>' . $item->title . '</h1>';
        echo '<br><b>Id</b>: ' . $item->id;
        echo '<br><b>SKU</b>: ' . $item->SKU;
        echo '<br><b>Merchant</b>: ' . $item->merchant;
        echo '</div>';
  }
    }
  }
  if ($found == "0") {
    echo 'No results found;
  }
  ?>

</body>

</html>

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

here are the variable $item->title which stores the product title, and it is coming by POST call from another page. And I can use it in the title If I get a proper solution.

[You can check here](https://Solutions%20https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62415/changing-document-title-only-on-a-custom-page-template)

This code I tried this in my function.php

```
    function wpse62415_filter_wp_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_page_template( 'details.php' ) ) {
        return 'I m the boat details page';
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wpse62415_filter_wp_title' );
```

The issue is the value of
Simply I just want to change the title with my product title name.

Comment: You’re already displaying the title in the template, so you know what the code is. You just need to use it inside the wp_title filter.

Comment: @JacobPeattie First of all Thank you for commenting, Yes you are right I'm displaying the title in the template but I want to show the dynamic value which is coming from $item->title, But I don't know how to use it inside wp-filter for dynamic value.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your life a little easier by moving the details fetching to an earlier point in the WordPress loading sequence and wrapping the data in a class. The object initialized from the class can then be used to provide the data to WordPress and to your template with filters.

For example you could have a handler class akin to this.

```
// Separate file or in functions.php
class My_Product_Details_Handler
{
    protected $product = null;

    public function __construct(int $product_id)
    {
        $this->setupProduct($product_id);
    }

    protected function setupProduct(int $product_id): void
    {
        $rss = simplexml_load_file('https://domain.com/xml');

        foreach ($rss->channel as $channel) {
            foreach ($channel->item as $item) {
                if ($item->id !== $product_id) {
                    continue;
                }

                $this->product = $item;
                break 2; // break both foreach loops
            }
        }
    }

    public function filter_wp_title(string $title, string $sep, string $seplocation): string
    {
        return $this->product ? $this->product->title : $title;
    }

    public function render_product_title(): void
    {
        echo $this->product ? $this->product->title : '';
    }

    public function provide_product_details()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }
}
```

An object could be created from the class for example on the `init` action. `template_redirect` could work too for providing the data to the front end.

```
// functions.php
add_action('init', 'init_my_product_details_handler');
function init_my_product_details_handler(): void {
    // Are we on the right template?
    if (! is_page_template('product-details.php')) {
        return;
    }
    
    // Get id from the url
    $product_id = !empty($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])
        ? (int) $_GET['id']
        : 0;

    // Do nothing, if there's no ID
    if (! $product_id) {
        return;
    }

    // Init handler
    $handler = new My_Product_Details_Handler($product_id);

    // Attach handler to relevant hooks
    add_filter( 'wp_title', [$handler, 'filter_wp_title'], 10, 3 );
    
    add_filter( 'my_product_details_data', [$handler, 'provide_product_details'] );
}
```

Then a small tweak to the template file. Using a filter to get the product data makes the template file a little cleaner looking.

```
// product-details.php template
<body>
    <?php
        $product_details = apply_filters( 'my_product_details_data', null );
        if ($product_details) {
            // render the details
        } else {
            echo 'No results found;
        }
    ?>
</body>
```